# Testing the Extension for a Visualforce page

Tags: unit-test, controller-extension

I am just curious about the following code, not able to achieve 100 % code coverage.

Following is the extension and its test class.

```
public class RW_EnquiryFormExtension {
  public String projects {
    get;
    set;
  }
   private RW_Project_Master__c objProject;


  public RW_EnquiryFormExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
  {
    if(projects!=null)
  objProject= [select id from RW_Project_Master__c where name = :projects];

  }
  public List <SelectOption >getactiveprojects()
  {
    List <SelectOption >options = new List <SelectOption >();
    List <RW_Project_Master__c >activeProjectList = new List <RW_Project_Master__c >();
    activeProjectList = [Select Id, name FROM RW_Project_Master__c where RecordType.name = 'Active Projects' ];
    options.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    for (Integer j = 0;j <activeProjectList.size();j ++)
    {
      options.add(new SelectOption(activeProjectList [j ].name, activeProjectList [j ].name));
    }
    return options;
  }

  public Lead lead {
    get {
      if (lead == null)
        lead = new Lead();
      return lead;
    }
    set;
  }


  // save button is clicked
  public PageReference save() {

    try {
    objProject= [select id from RW_Project_Master__c where name = :projects];
    lead.OwnerId=Userinfo.getUserId();
        lead.RW_Project__c=objProject.id;
      insert lead; // inserts the new record into the database
    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error creating new Lead.'));
      return null;
    }

    // if successfully inserted new lead, then displays the thank you page.
    return Page.RW_LeadCreated_ThankYou;
  }

}
```

Following is the test clas for the same extension:

```
@isTest
private class RW_EnquiryForm_Tracker {
  static private Lead objLead;
   static private RW_Project_Master__c objProject;
   static private RecordType objRT;
  static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
          LoadData();
        PageReference pageRef = Page.Rw_Enquiry_Form;
       Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);


     Apexpages.StandardController stdController = new Apexpages.StandardController(objLead);  
     RW_EnquiryFormExtension objTestLead = new RW_EnquiryFormExtension(stdController);
      objTestLead.projects = 'Grove';
      String nextPage;

      objTestLead.getactiveprojects();

      objTestLead.lead.lastName = 'Test Lead';
     // objTestLead.save();
      nextPage = objTestLead.save().getURL();
      System.assertEquals('/apex/rw_leadcreated_thankyou',nextPage); 

     objTestLead = new RW_EnquiryFormExtension(stdController);
      objTestLead.getactiveprojects();
      objTestLead.projects = 'Grove';
     // objTestLead.lead.lastName = 'Test Lead';
     objTestLead.save();


  }

      private static void LoadData()
    {
        CreateProject();
        CreateLead();
    }

      static void CreateProject()
    {
        objRT = [Select id ,Name from recordtype where SObjectType = 'RW_Project_Master__c' and name = 'Active Projects'];
        objProject = new RW_Project_Master__c();
        objProject.Name = 'Grove';
        objProject.RW_Email__c = 'grove.raywhite@gmail.com';
        objProject.Expected_Settlement__c = System.today();
        objProject.RecordTypeId = objRT.id;
        insert objProject;
    }
    static void CreateLead()
      {
        objLead = new Lead();
        objLead.lastname = 'Zen';
        objLead.email = 'ankit@gmail.com';
        objLead.phone = '9990665834';
        objLead.RW_Project__c = objProject.id;
        //objLead.RW_Buyer_Profile__c = 'FIRB';       
  }
}
```

I am not able to cover the single line in the constructor. i.e

```
  objProject= [select id from RW_Project_Master__c where name = :projects];
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is the very first thing that is run in the class. At that time, the `projects` variable will always be null, thus the line containing the query will never be run.

I think the easiest solution will be to remove that line from your class, as it will never be called anyway.

Alternatively, if you do need to load data in your constructor, make sure that you fill the `projects` variable in the constructor, or in the `get` of the `projects` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Guy . But what happens if we want this value to be set as soon as the VF page loads and then fetch some values in SOQL in a constructor? Don't we have any solution for that. Can we use setter method for the same?

Comment: You can default a value for the projects variable in the constructor. Then the query will run.